# LINQpad can't connect to SQL developer server

Tags: sql-server, linqpad

I know this is a dumb question but it's really impeding my progress.
When using LINQpad I am able to easily connect to my SQL Server Express, but I cannot figure out the connection string for my `SQLDEVELOPER` server.

Here is the information I can find regarding my server:

[image]

[image]

Would this be enough information to figure out the connection string I need?
I have tried heaps of combinations of `MSSQLSERVER` / `V-ADLWS12` / `MSSQL14` and still nothing.

Thanks for any help

Comment: tried refer to https://www.connectionstrings.com/ ?

Comment: I didn't know that existed - but it's bound to help, I'll take a gander. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the **instance name** column in your second screenshot:

- the `MSSQLSERVER` instance is the **default, unnamed** instance which you can connect to use `.` (means: local server - this machine), `(local)` or `localhost` (or also: `machinename`)
- Any other instance is a **named** instance, which you can connect to using `.\SQLEXPRESS`, or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`, or  `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`, or `yourmachinename\SQLEXPRESS`
- If you're connecting to a **remote** SQL Server, just replace the `.` with the machine name of that remote SQL Server machine

Answer (score 3):

....All I needed for the connection string was a dot.

```
.
```

I'm more happy than confused